# Show input right after label

Tags: html, css

I need to show (within a div tag) a label and right next to the label an input. I am using bootstrap css and my code is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="control-group">
             <label class="control-label" for="txtInput">Enter Text:</label>
                 <div class="controls">
                       <input id="txtId" class="input-medium" name="txtInput" />
                 </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

No matter what I do there is a space between the label ("Enter Text:") and the left margin of Input.

How do I change the HTML or CSS to accomplish this?   TIA

Answer (score 1):

To adjust the position of only your input field you should be able to just apply the "position" CSS property of that element. Once you set that "position" property as relative you can move the element's position relative to its initial starting location using top,bottom,left, and right.

In the below example I moved your input field 5 pixels to the left of where it normally would be.

```
<style>
  .controls{
    position:relative;
    left:-5px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing any whitespace between the elements.  For example:

```
<label class="control-label" for="txtInput">Enter Text:</label><div class="controls"><input id="txtId" class="input-medium" name="txtInput" /></div>
```

Then, just remove the margin or padding of the div or input, if you want them to be placed right next to each other.  The whitespace between them is rendered, so you'll have to remove it.  Another approach I've seen is (but never used) is to put an HTML comment between the elements instead, like this:

```
<label class="control-label" for="txtInput">Enter Text:</label><!--
--><div class="controls"><!--
       --><input id="txtId" class="input-medium" name="txtInput" />
   </div>
```

See if either of those help.  I recently ran into this problem where I was getting unexpected whitespace between my labels and inputs, and I couldn't remove it without using negative margin, which I didn't like.  The solution I found was to remove the whitespace as in the first example.  It doesn't look too pretty in the code, but it works.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions.
Removing white spaces by inserting comment between element didn't work.
Setting Left position or Margin-Left to the number -100px works.  But I am concenred that hard-coding this will not look well on every browser.  I wish I could find a solution without hard-coding this.  I will keep looking.

Comment: Good luck.  Could you post the CSS being applied to these elements as well?  That might help track down the issue.

Comment: I found the solution to how to do what I needed. I was using bootstrap classes "form-horizontal" and "controls" These classes would set the value of margin-left to 180px. So my Input would alway be 180px to the right of the label.  Once I override this value in my class, the Input appears right next to the label.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a negative margin on input-medium to force it to be closer to the label:

```
    div.controls {
        display:inline;
    }
    .input-medium {
        margin-left:-4px;
    }
```